# Number with Dash Keeps Subtracting in Transfer

Tags: sql, vba, excel

I have a sheet in Excel with numbers formatted as text like this -

> 1-123456789

I have written some VBA to transfer this number into an SQL database table as below -

```
With Sheets("Sheet1")
conn.Execute "INSERT INTO dbo.A_MyNos ([No])" & _
             "VALUES (" & .Cells(1, 1) & ")"
End With
```

Unfortunately, the number keeps getting inserted into the table as -123456788!  It appears to be running it through as a subtraction formula and I have no idea why.

Could anybody guide me on the correct method to avoid this?

I've also tried changing the cell format and using `CStr(.Cells...)` in the VBA without success.

Think I'll try to enter the cell as 3 separate strings and concatenate them in the SQL but that seems awkward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because for `.Cells(1, 1)` beeing `1-123456789`

```
conn.Execute "INSERT INTO dbo.A_MyNos ([No])" & "VALUES (" & .Cells(1, 1) & ")"
```

evaluates to

```
INSERT INTO dbo.A_MyNos ([No]) VALUES (1-123456789)
```

so it starts calculating in SQL.

If you want to insert it as a string then the value should be within `""` like:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.A_MyNos ([No]) VALUES ("1-123456789")
```

Therefore you need to add double `""` in VBA

```
conn.Execute "INSERT INTO dbo.A_MyNos ([No])" & "VALUES (""" & .Cells(1, 1) & """)"
```

Comment: Thanks PEH.  Seems obvious now!  I used single quotes though as it was neater - `"VALUES ('" & .Cells(1, 1) & "')"`, as per Jeeped's answer.  Will mark this as correct though.

Answer (score 2):

Wrap the value in single quotes and use the cell's Text property..

```
With Sheets("Sheet1")
conn.Execute "INSERT INTO dbo.A_MyNos ([No])" & _
             "VALUES ('" & .Cells(1, 1).Text & "')"
End With
```

The [No] fiels should be nvarchar or equivalent.

Comment: Thanks @Jeeped.  The one thing that hadn't occurred to me!  I haven't used VBA in ages.  I used the single quotes but the .text property wasn't necessary.  Upvoted, but marking PEH's answer as correct for the additional background info, hope you don't mind.

Comment: No worries. I think he even beat me to the submit button by ~30 seconds as well!

Comment: Well, you were both crazy quick and I appreciate the help.

Comment: btw, the .Text property was just in case custom number formatting was involved for future viewers.